# "Workspace virtulization" vs. Docker container

Tags: docker, virtualization

There is a [Wikipedia article about somewhat called "workspace virtualization"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workspace_virtualization). The article isn't perfect and doesn't have any good references, but there some another ones:

- https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/5951-workspace-virtualization.html
- https://www.cio.com/article/3104533/virtualization/workspace-virtualization.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symantec_Workspace_Virtualization

I'm trying to understand how this "workspace virtualization" differs from Docker containers in that case that we have multiple applications inside single container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect that term to include setups where you have a complete desktop environment, with multiple *interactive* bundled applications, that either you can log into remotely or you can distribute as a self-contained virtual machine.

That might include:

- Multiple applications bundled into one environment
- A notion of a "user"
- Data persisted across login sessions
- The ability to transparently migrate the session across hosts
- Running interactive GUI applications, not server-type applications

All of the above things are significant challenges in Docker.  In Docker you typically have:

- Only one thing running in a container
- Run as the Unix `root` user or a single, non-configurable, system account
- Content is lost when the container exits unless storage was explicitly configured at startup time
- Migration is usually done by moving data (if any) and recreating the environment, not a live migration
- Server-type programs, like HTTP-based services

I might implement the kind of "workspace virtualization" you're asking about using a full virtual machine environment, which has more of the right properties.  It wouldn't be impossible *per se* to implement it on Docker, but you'd have to reinvent a lot of the pieces that get omitted in a typical Docker setup to make it lighter-weight, and you'd still be missing things like live migrations that are very mature in VM setups.

Comment: Summary: WV could be implemented with VM (just use VM and that's all - there are no things to tune up), but it will be resource usage overhead. Also, it could be implemented with Docker - without such resource overhead, but with a lot of headache.

Comment: I'd estimate the resource usage of Docker to not be significantly lower in this case, since you'd have to run all of the other parts of a "full operating system" for the desktop setup to work.